# ShadowMap Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js r73 and I've two problems with shadowmaps.

First, when I set 'logarithmicDepthBuffer' with true for my renderer, I don't have anymore shadows.

Second, I can't see shadow on my ground. My ground is PlaneBufferGeometry with MeshPhongMaterial (without texture) and have 'receiveShadow' property enabled.

Ideas? Thx

Comment: was a problem of too strong light

Comment: Are your objects casting shadows?

Answer (score 0):

Set your light object `castShadow` property to true.